# How to create an RSS feed for my blog on my own hosting?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I just installed a Blubrry plugin in my WordPress to create an RSS feed for my podcasts that I want to upload.

But what is the next step after installing and activating that plugin? Does installing the plugin automatically create the RSS feed? Or how do I create the RSS feed?

Answer (score 4):

WordPress creates feeds at `[site_url]/feed/` by default. Check there e.g. `www.example.com/feed`.

There should also be a link added to all pages in the `<header>`:

```
<link
rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="website title Feed" href="[site_url]/feed/" />
```

The title is usually pulled from your WordPress site description, editable in admin area.
With this header link users with an RSS extension can 'discover' your feed. You can also add a link on each page of your site (recommended) to the RSS feed stream (http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_publishing.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress even creates RSS feeds for yout tags and categories. You can call the category or tag slug with a `/feed/` behind the url (`[site_url]/category/test/feed/` or `[site_url]/tag/test/feed/`).